Visualizing the oscillating circle with 1/k radius
Working through the first few units of calc 2, we are learning about curvature and what it means as a number. I asked my teacher this... and got, and realized that it demonstrates 1/R of the oscillating circle, like a tangent line, but it's a circle, and we wanted to visualize it in desmos-3d. We were able to get parameterize the function for the oscillating sphere and the plane intersection that would result in the oscillating circle, but cannot figure out how to restrict the visualization to the intersection. Reading some other posts, it seems like restricting a function to the intersection between a plane and circle is trickier than most, so does anyone know how to find the function for this oscillating circle? And please explain because the whole class is stumped.
Thankyou!

Hint: The center of the circle is $\vec{r}(t) + \frac{1}{\kappa(t)}\hat{n}(t)$

osculating circle … The circle needs to be tangent to the curve at the point and have the same curvature. The curvature of a circle of radius $a$ is $1/a$.
